# How to Map user to Rest APIs in Spring BOOT?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My requirement is I want to restrict the user to access some particular API i.e Grouping the users to access some API. For example:
Let's say I have users as A, B, C, D and Apis as a, b, c, d, e, f, i, j. I want user A to access a, b, and c API; user B to access b, c, d; user C to access e, f, i API and user D to access D API.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's possible using database create a table and grant api according to user

Comment: @AmmarAli Can you add an example. I want a solution similar to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other considerations, the easiest solution might be to assign GrantedAuthorities for each endpoint.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(
            User.builder()
                    .username("A")
                    .password("secret")
                    .authorities("a","b","c")
                    .build());
    return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by GrantedAuthorities ? Can you give an example?

Comment: You tag spring-security on your question, so I guess you have a `AuthenticationProvider` or `UserDetailsService` that keeps track of the users and their permissions.